# Fullscreen HTML Element using window.innerHeight/Width different with DOCTYPE

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fullscreen

I'm trying to make an HTML5 canvas element fullscreen with the window.innerHeight and innerWidth properties.

Unfortunately, on Chrome 10, when I set use the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

...there is some extra scrolling space indicated by scroll bars which shouldn't appear.

Without a doctype, everything is fine.

The element is an HTML5 canvas, so styling with 100% will only stretch the content.

Is it worth using a doctype which breaks my functionality (without which might be bad?), or should I subtract, say, 15px from the values in order to keep scroll bars from appearing? (which is kludgy)

Comment: By "fullscreen" you really mean "filling the browser window"?

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for clarifying that; that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is surely because of the default padding found on the body element of the page. Remove all default padding and margins using:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Just for `body` would be enough.

Comment: Yes but an old fashioned global padding/margin reset is usually a good idea with these things.

Comment: Thanks guys. I had those styles in there earlier, but it must not've been included with the document or something. I went ahead anyway and wrote a bunch of JavaScript, and now everything works fine for some reason. Thanks again!